# Laravel Carbon error with year in difference between dates

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

Good afternoon...
I try to make the difference in years between the current date and a date in the database like this:

```
$final = '2016-05-10'; //date database
$hoy = \Carbon\Carbon::now(); //today
$fecha_ingreso = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $final);

$diff = $hoy->diffInYears($fecha_ingreso); //diff
```

But when doing a var_dump() of $fecha_ingreso it shows me the following:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)#259 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2155-05-10 22:27:09.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(3) "UTC" }
```

The day and the month are ok but the year is not, why can this error be ??
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: isn't your machine date ok?

Comment: Yes, the date is correct

Comment: whats is output of var_dump( \Carbon\Carbon::now());
and  var_dump($fecha_ingreso); ?

Comment: If I do var_dump() from the current date it shows me fine, but the date of the database does not. Day and month are correct but not year.

Comment: what's the type of the **final** column in the database? Date, DateTime or Timestamp?

Comment: It´s Date type.

Comment: try to casts **final** as a date or add it to **protected $dates** in the model and see what the result you have `var_dump($model->final)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume you want the difference in number of years, try this.

```
$dbDate = \Carbon\Carbon::parse('2016-05-10');
$diffYears = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffInYears($dbDate);

// $diffYears is 1
```